# Efficient implementation of mpi All-to-All Scatter/Gather

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Each of my processes has an array of values `v` and an array of process IDs `pid` of the same size. `pid[i]` specifies to which process to send item `v[i]`.

I need to implement a scatter operation (and of course the corresponding gather operation).
The array of process IDs very likely contains only (but not exclusively) neighbouring processes (in the sense of a cartesian topology) and most of the time only its own process ID. (the one that `MPI_Comm_rank()` returns). Also the map is initialized only once and stays the same during my whole computation whereas the scatter/gather operation is called very often.

I am halfway through my own implementation, starting with a sort of the values such that neighbouring elements are sent to the same process and a lot of ISend's and IRecv's later on. Now I came across the `MPI_Alltoallv` function and I'm wondering if I am better off with my own coding or if I should use the MPI internal function. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that your processes will always be communicating in a certain topology, one of the things that can really decrease the number of messages you need to send is neighborhood collectives. I won't go through an entire tutorial here, but the basic idea is that you provide your topology information to MPI, then use special collective functions to do your communication. The special functions are:

```
MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLGATHER(sendbuf, sendcount, sendtype, recvbuf, recvcount, recvtype, comm)
MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLGATHERV(sendbuf, sendcount, sendtype, recvbuf, recvcounts, displs, recvtype, comm)
MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLTOALL(sendbuf, sendcount, sendtype, recvbuf, recvcount, recvtype, comm)
MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLTOALLV(sendbuf, sendcounts, sdispls, sendtype, recvbuf, recvcounts, rdispls, recvtype, comm)
MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLTOALLW(sendbuf, sendcounts, sdispls, sendtypes, recvbuf, recvcounts, rdispls, recvtypes, comm)
```

plus all of the non-blocking variants. By using these, you don't have to write your own collective functions. You can just use the built in stuff from MPI that's going to be better optimized and easier to read.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I haven't noticed these before. I will benchmark what I already have and then decide whether to optimize further.  I have some hope that the overhead of sending zero sized messages in mpi_alltoallv is not that striking.

Comment: The overhead of the messages isn't high, but that's not the big timesink there. Most of your time will go into the fact that you have to synchronize with all other processes. This may not make a big difference if you're running at a relatively small scale (<1000 processes), but if you get into medium and large scales it can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, one can't be sure, but in general using the MPI collective call will result in better performance, and more readable code, than using separate ISend and IRecv calls for the constituent parts.  In particular, the MPI_Alltoallv function will batch the neighboring values into a single send, or receive, on each rank listed and do this without the overhead of creating all of the individual structures necessary for individual non-blocking send/receives.

The big exception to this rule is where converting your data into the form expected by the collective is impractical.  Since your pattern stays the same over the course of the application, this exception likely does not apply to you.

Comment: ahh thx, I think I'll try it then, do you know if it allows for zero sized chunks to send?

Comment: Zero sized chunks should be fine, the standard specifies that the {send,recv}counts array elements must be non-negative, but may be zero.  There is always a chance that a particular MPI may not allow this, but as far as the standard is concerned it's allowed so long as both sides agree that the size is zero.